# Including plus/minus into the graph of function in tikz

Tags: graphs

I'm trying to plot the graph of y²=x²√(4+x) but the code below doesn't give a desired result. Is there a way to include plus or minus into the functions to be plotted.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ variable=\x, smooth, blue, scale=0.2, domain=-4:2]  plot  (\x, -sqrt{\x*\x*sqrt{4+\x}});
\draw[ variable=\x, smooth, blue, scale=0.2, domain=-4:2]plot  (\x, sqrt{\x*\x*sqrt{4+\x}});
```

Comment: Please supplement your code snippet as _complete examples_ which begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sqrt(...)` instead of `sqrt{...}`, see [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 95.3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-5, 0) -- +(10, 0);
  \draw[->] (0, -3) -- +(0, 6);
  \draw[variable=\x, samples=200, smooth, blue, domain=-4:2]
    plot (\x, { sqrt(\x*\x*sqrt(4+\x))})
    plot (\x, {-sqrt(\x*\x*sqrt(4+\x))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With use of the `pgfplots` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
  ticks=none,
  xmin=-4.4, xmax=2.4,
domain=-4:2,
samples=201,
no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick, color=blue!50}
                ]
\addplot    { sqrt(x*x*sqrt(4+x))};
\addplot    {-sqrt(x*x*sqrt(4+x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]